# Best Android Phone for testing android application on real android device

Tags: android, android-emulator

Tell which android phone is batter for the testing of the android application on real phone. And what are the major points have to remind while go to purchase Android device for development. I am thinking for "SAMSUNG GALAXY YS5630" my main concern is regarding to the regular update of the version of the phone. IS SAMSUNG provide version update features.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "best device" for testing in general.

What you need to do is figure out what versions of Android you want to support - is it only 4.0 or do you want to support 2.1 and up?

When you have made up your mind you go and buy a device. Genrally devices are backward compatible meaning a 4.0 device will be able to run an app targeting 2.1.

The major problem/issue in testing on devices is that the manifactures (HTC, Samsung etc.) have modified the OS slighty increasing the risk of weird behavoiur on different devices.

If you want the best testing on devices - you need 3-5 devices with different screen density and size from 2-3 major manifactures.

Answer (score 1):

For a testing device I'd recommend going for a phone with excellent developer support for custom ROMS. That way you can test across various versions of Android. The Nexus line, and any of the top tier HTC or Samsung phones should meet that criteria.

The site [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) has forum sections for almost every phone, there you can guage developer interest.

Of course be aware such procedures will likely invalidate a phones warranty.

Comment: I strongly advise the nexus line, and that advise should probably be good for a while, as they are supported by google by definition of being on that line.